# adding a link to the slide breaks the layout

Tags: nuxt3, vue3-carousel

Working with Nuxt 3.8 & vue3-carousel-nuxtv1.1.0. I've also tried nuxt-swiperv1.2.2 with exactly the same result. Also get the same result whether I use an anchor tag or NuxtLink although oddly, the issue only appears when the href (or to) attribute have been added to the tag.
This works as expectd, ie. no horizontal scrollbar
flashing at the bottom of the screen:

````
```<template>
  <carousel :breakpoints="breakpoints" :settings="settings">
    <slide v-for="product in collection.products.edges" :key="product.node.id">
      <div class="flex place-content-center">
        <span>{{ product.node.title }}</span>
      </div>
    </slide>
    <template #addons>
      <Navigation />
    </template>
  </carousel>
</template>```
````

This breaks the layout:

````
```<template>
  <carousel :breakpoints="breakpoints" :settings="settings">
    <slide v-for="product in collection.products.edges" :key="product.node.id">
      <div class="flex place-content-center">
        <a href="#"
          ><span>{{ product.node.title }}</span></a
        >
      </div>
    </slide>
    <template #addons>
      <Navigation />
    </template>
  </carousel>
</template>```
````

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8ZTc.png]

I've been chasing this error for days!! Any help gratefully received.